# Post value from ASP.NET page to C#

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, screen-resolution

I have a JavaScript function as follows:

```
function getWindowSize() {
   test.value = $(window).width();
   test2.value = $(window).height();
}

window.onresize = getWindowSize;
```

And in the ASP.NET page:

```
<input type="text" id="test2" value="Test"/>  
<input type="text" id="test" value="Test"/>
```

This populates the fields when the screen size changes. When I put the page elements to have `runat="server"` they don't populate the screen size and cannot capture it server side.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `ClientID` if you have server tag. You are not currently using getElementById but you should to get the DOM element for better browser compatibility. If you have framework 4 and above you can use [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and do it without `ClientID`

**Javascript**

```
function getWindowSize() {
       document.getElementById('<%= test.ClientID %>').value = $(window).width();
       document.getElementById('<%= test2.ClientID %>').value = $(window).height();
}
window.onresize = getWindowSize;
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="test2" value="Test" runat="server" />  
<input type="text" id="test" value="Test" runat="server" />
```

Comment: Thanks. I have tried this and the html elements to get any values from the java script..

Comment: Is your prblem solved? your comment is quite ambiguous for me

Comment: Check it now, make sure you have runat="server"

Comment: any suggestions on how I can now capture this in c# on the server side? I keep getting the original value they are set at "test". in Page_load I am capturing the value of test.value but i think its doing that before the java script is setting its new value

Comment: You can use some hidden field, make it runat server and assign the changed value, extract them in code behind.

Answer (score 1):

Since I cannot see the full code, I am going to assume ASP.NET replaces Id attributes with generated ones (something like _ctl$Container$test). As a workaround, if you use jQuery you can use CSS classes:

**Javascript**

```
function getWindowSize() {
       $('.WidthValue') = $(window).width();
       $('.HeightValue') = $(window).height();
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="test" value="Test" class="WidthValue" runat="server" /> 
<input type="text" id="test2" value="Test" class="HeightValue" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `Masterpages`? Because when adding `ASP.NET` form controls using masterpages they use a prefix to identity the controls:

```
<input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_txtName" class="textfield" type="text" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$txtName">
```

Where **ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_** is the prefix of the masterpage.

This can be the cause why your javascript function doesn't populate the fields.
How do you identify your objects test and test2?

Comment: Yes I am using master pages. Looking at it the id changes to "MainContent_test2"

Comment: How do you identify your javascript objects test and test2?

Comment: in the javascript I use test.value = $(window).width(); to identify test to assign the screen width